# Segmentation fault when running C program in different environments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, newline, valgrind, portability

I've recently started programming in C and I'm having trouble submitting a homework on a site called [run.codes](https://run.codes). **My program works fine in my computer and in several online compilers, but run.codes is giving me a "Segmentation fault" error on every test case**. I suspected it had something to do with the C version that the site is using, so I tried to make my program compatible with older standards (C99), but it still not working.

Of all the online compilers I've tested, only [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c99_online.php) one gave me the same error as run.codes. In all the others, my program worked as expected. Since the "segmentation fault" error usually indicates that an unallowed attempt to access memory has ocurred, I've tried using Valgrind to track possible errors. My program happens to have several, even though it compiles and works fine in most environments.

Below is my program. I apologize the over-commenting and for the use of portuguese. My professor demands it to be that way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
 * Definicao de constantes. 
 */
//Tamanhos limites (por seguranca, sao usados valores maiores do que o necessario!)
#define MAX_CHARS 600
#define MAX_SENTENCES 100

//Tipos de perguntas
enum {
    POSITIVOS = 101, NEGATIVOS = 102, PALAVRA = 103
};

//Listas de palavras
const char *POSITIVE_WORDS[] = {"bom", "maravilhoso", "otimo", "sensacional", "excelente", "adorei", "gostei", "amei", "eficiente", "boa", "maravilhosa", "otima"};
const char *NEGATIVE_WORDS[] = {"detestei", "odiei", "ruim", "pessimo", "terrivel", "raiva", "odio", "pessima", "lento", "lenta", "fragil", "desisti"};
const char *INVERSION_WORDS[] = {"nao", "jamais", "nunca"};


/*
 * Implementacao de funcoes nao existentes no C99.
 */
//strdup (copia uma string)
char *my_strdup(char *src)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src) + 1; //o +1 serve para que o simbolo \0 seja copiado tambem
    char *s = malloc(len);

    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return (char *) memcpy(s, src, len); //memcpy retornara um ponteiro para s
}
//strsep (separa uma string usando um delimitador)
char *my_strsep(char** stringp, const char* delim)
{
  char *p, *start = *stringp;
  p = (start != NULL) ? strpbrk(start, delim) : NULL;

  if (p == NULL) {
    *stringp = NULL;
  }
  else {
    *p = '\0';
    *stringp = p + 1;
  }

  return start;
}


/*
 * Estrutura de um produto.
 */
typedef struct
{
    char *name; //nome do produto
    char sentences[MAX_SENTENCES][MAX_CHARS]; //sentencas que se referem ao produto
    int sentences_count; //numero de sentencas que se referem ao produto    
} Product;


/*
 * Associa uma sentenca a um produto.
 *
 * Product *p: produto em questao.
 * char *sentence: string contendo a sentenca.
 */
void addSentenceToProduct(Product *p, char *sentence)
{
    if(p->sentences_count < MAX_SENTENCES) {
        strcpy(p->sentences[p->sentences_count], sentence);
        p->sentences_count++;
    }
}


/*
 * Remove o ultimo caractere de uma string caso ele seja igual a c.
 *
 * char *str: a string que deseja-se alterar.
 * char c: o caractere que deve estar na ultima posicao da string.
 */
void removeLastChar(char *str, char c)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    if(len > 0 && str[len-1] == c)
        str[len-1] = '\0';
}


/*
 * Le sentencas com multiplas palavras e as armazena na matriz dada.
 *
 * int count: quantidade de sentencas.
 * char sentencas[][]: matriz onde as sentencas serao armazenadas.
 */
void readSentences(int count, char sentences[][MAX_CHARS])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fgets(sentences[i], MAX_CHARS, stdin);

        //ignora a entrada caso ela seja apenas um line breaker
        if(sentences[i][0] == '\n') {
            i--;
            continue;
        }

        //remove o line breaker do final da string, caso haja um
        removeLastChar(sentences[i], '\n');
    }
}


/*
 * Le sentencas na qual um produto é especificado no inicio. A funcao strsep() é usada para separar o produto do restante da sentenca.
 *
 * int count: quantidade de sentencas.
 * Product products[]: lista com os produtos
 * 
 */
int readSentencesWithProducts(int count, Product products[])
{
    char temp[MAX_SENTENCES][MAX_CHARS];
    readSentences(count, temp); //lendo a frase completa

    int productsCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char *temp2 = my_strdup(temp[i]);

        char *productName = my_strsep(&temp2, ";");
        removeLastChar(productName, ' '); //remove o espaco no final do nome do produto

        //Verifica se o produto ja esta na lista
        int index = -1; 
        for(int j = 0; j < productsCount; j++) {
            if(strcmp(productName, products[j].name) == 0) {
                index = j;
            }
        }

        //Novo produto, caso nao haja nenhum com o nome especificado
        if(index < 0) {
            index = productsCount;
            productsCount++;

            products[index].name = productName;
            products[index].sentences_count = 0;
        }

        //Descobre a sentenca e a adiciona ao produto associado
        char *sentence = my_strsep(&temp2, ";"); //separando sentencas
        addSentenceToProduct(&products[index], sentence);

        free(temp2); //liberando a memoria alocada com o strdup()
    }

    return productsCount;
}


/*
 * Retorna o index (referente a array de produtos) do produto ao qual a pergunta se refere. Retorna -1 caso o produto nao seja encontrado.
 *
 * char *question: referencia para a string que contem a pergunta.
 * Products products[]: array que contem os produtos.
 * int count: numero de produtos
 */
int findProductIndex(char *question, Product products[], int count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(strstr(question, products[i].name) != NULL)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}


/*
 * Busca pela intencao da pergunta (o que ela quer saber).
 *
 * char *question: referencia para a string contendo a pergunta.
 */
int getQuestionIntent(char *question) 
{
    if(strstr(question, "palavra") != NULL)
        return PALAVRA;
    if(strstr(question, "negativos") != NULL)
        return NEGATIVOS;

    return POSITIVOS;
}


/*
 * Retorna a quantidade de vezes que uma dada palavra aparece em uma sentenca.
 *
 * char *word: palavra cujo uso sera contado.
 * char *sentence: sentenca que sera analisada.
 */
int countWordUsage(const char *word, char *sentence)
{
    int counter = 0;

    char *temp = my_strdup(sentence);
    char *resultWord = my_strsep(&temp, " ");

    while(resultWord != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(word, resultWord) == 0) 
            counter++;

        resultWord = my_strsep(&temp, " ");
    }       

    free(temp);
    return counter;
}


/*
 * Retorna 1 caso a palavra dada seja um inversor e 0 caso nao.
 *
 * char *word: palavra que sera checada.
 */
int isInversor(char *word)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(strcmp(word, INVERSION_WORDS[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
 * Retorna 1 caso a palavra dada pertenca a classe das "positivas".
 *
 * char *word: palavra que sera analisada.
 */
int isPositive(char *word) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if(strcmp(word, POSITIVE_WORDS[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
 * Retorna 1 caso a palavra dada pertenca a classe das "negativas".
 *
 * char *word: palavra que sera analisada.
 */
int isNegative(char *word) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if(strcmp(word, NEGATIVE_WORDS[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


/*
 * Retorna a quantidade de vezes que palavras de uma dada lista, levando-se em consideracao inversores, aparecem nas sentencas de um produto.
 *
 * Product p: produto que sera analisado.
 * int dividend: o dividendo da razao (POSITIVO ou NEGATIVO)
 */
double countPosNegRatio(Product p, const int dividend)
{
    int pos = 0, neg = 0, lastInversor = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < p.sentences_count; i++) 
    {
        char *sentence = my_strdup(p.sentences[i]);
        char *word = my_strsep(&sentence, " ");

        int countedPos = 0, countedNeg = 0; //verifica se ja foi contada uma opiniao positiva ou negativa na sentenca em questao    
        while(word != NULL) 
        {
            if(isInversor(word)) {
                lastInversor = 1;
            }
            else {
                if(lastInversor > 3) {
                    //Positiva
                    if(isPositive(word) && !countedPos) {
                        pos++;
                        countedPos = 1;
                    }
                    //Negativa
                    else if(isNegative(word) && !countedNeg) {
                        neg++;
                        countedNeg = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //Negativa (inversao)
                    if(isPositive(word) && !countedNeg) {
                        neg++;
                        countedNeg = 1;
                    }
                    //Positiva(inversao)
                    else if(isNegative(word) && !countedPos) {
                        pos++;
                        countedPos = 1;
                    }
                }
                lastInversor++;
            }
            word = my_strsep(&sentence, " ");
        }
        free(sentence);
    }

    int total = pos + neg;
    return (dividend == POSITIVOS) ? (double) pos/total : (double) neg/total;
}


/*
 * Processa e responde a uma pergunta.
 *
 * char *question: pergunta que deve ser respondida.
 * Products products[]: lista de produtos
 * int count: quantidade total de produtos
 */
void processQuestion(char *question, Product products[], int count)
{
    int pIndex = findProductIndex(question, products, count);

    if(pIndex >= 0) 
    {
        Product p = products[pIndex];
        int intent = getQuestionIntent(question);

        switch(intent)
        {
            case POSITIVOS:
            case NEGATIVOS:
            {
                printf("%.1lf%%\n", 100*countPosNegRatio(p, intent));
                break;
            }
            case PALAVRA:
            {

                //descobre a palavra que se deseja buscar
                char *temp = my_strdup(question);
                my_strsep(&temp, " "); //descarta a primeira palavra
                char *word = my_strsep(&temp, " "); //armazena a segunda palavra

                //checa quantas vezes a palavra apareceu
                int counter = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < p.sentences_count; i++) {
                    counter += countWordUsage(word, p.sentences[i]);
                }

                printf("%d\n", counter);
                break;
            }
            default:
                printf("Nao foi possivel detectar a intencao da pergunta!\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Produto nao encontrado!\n");
    }
}


/*
 * MAIN
 */
int main()
{
    int sentences_count, questions_count; 
    scanf("%d %d", &sentences_count, &questions_count);

    Product products[MAX_SENTENCES]; //armazena os produtos e suas respectivas sentencas
    int products_count = readSentencesWithProducts(sentences_count, products);

    char questions[MAX_SENTENCES][MAX_CHARS]; //armazena as perguntas
    readSentences(questions_count, questions);

    for(int i = 0; i < questions_count; i++) {
        processQuestion(questions[i], products, products_count);
    }


    /*
    //DEBUG
    for(int i = 0; i < productsCount; i++) {
        Product p = products[i];
        printf("-> %s:\n", p.name);
        for(int j = 0; j < p.sentences_count; j++) {
            printf("    %d - %s\n", j, p.sentences[j]); 
        }
    }
    */

    return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to read comments about certain products and then answer some questions, like *"how many times was the word X used?"* or *"what's the percentage of positive comments about product Y?"*. The two first integers given as input specify, respectively, the number of comments and the number of questions. The rest of the input consists on all the comments followed by all the questions. Each comment is formatted this way: *"name of the product ; comment"*. The output consists of an answer for each of the questions.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/ZsxsHcDY) is the log generated by Valgrind when I use the input below:

```
3 1
Televisor LG ; adorei o televisor lg ele e muito funcional Ø
Laptop HP ; nao gostei desse notebook pois ele esquenta muito Ø
Celular Motorola ; o formato do celular e muito bom bom mesmo bom demais Ø
palavra bom em Celular Motorola
```

The expected output (3), is given by the program. I'm using the following command to compile my code:

```
gcc trab.c -o trab -Wall -ggdb3
```

And the following parameters to initialize Valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=valgrind-out.txt ./trab
```

Finally, having given you all this information, my question is: **why does my program only work on certain environments and what can I do to solve this?** I hate that the post ended up this big, but since the problem is weird, I've felt that I should give all the information I could. Thanks for your time!

**Note:** my operational system is Ubuntu 19.04 and these ([here](https://repl.it/languages/c), [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler), [here](https://www.codechef.com/ide) and [here](https://csacademy.com/workspace/)) are some of the online compilers in which my program has run successfully. And [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c99_online.php) is the online compiler in which I get a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Your program is using a lot of stack space in a single function (which is also what valgrind is complaining about). Your `main` alone requires more than 6 MB of stack.

Comment: As a quick and dirty check to see whether running out of stack is the problem, you could declare `products` and `questions` as `static` and see if it still crashes.

Comment: ... why are you changing the declaration of `products_count`?

Comment: ops, you are right, I didn't notice. I've now correctly tried what you suggested, but I'm still getting seg fault: `timeout: the monitored command dumped core
sh: line 1: 161716 Segmentation fault      timeout 10s main`

Comment: Does valgrind have anything interesting to say with the new code?

Comment: No, it hasn't =[

Comment: OT:  strongly suggest replacing: `gcc trab.c -o trab -Wall -ggdb3`  with `gcc trab.c -o trab -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -ggdb3`

Comment: looking at the log from valgrind, this entry: `Invalid write of size 8
==778==    at 0x109C8D: main (trab.c:393)`  shows that we are not seeing the same source code as valgrind did.  That line `393` is in an area that is commented out in the code we are seeing.   Please post the same code that is being seen by valgrind

Comment: in function: `readSentences()`  a call to `fgets()` is performed without checking that the function was successful.  So the array: `sentences[]` could have uninitiated entries.  I.E. the original garbage would still be in one (or more) of the entries in `sentences[]`  and if that garbage doesn't happen to contain a '\0' then the function: `removeLastChar()` which calls `strlen()`  will be accessing far beyond the upper bounds of the array `sentences[]`  which can/will result in a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `char sentences[MAX_SENTENCES][MAX_CHARS]; `  This HUGE array is on the stack.  Suggest moving it to 'file scope' by `static char sentences[MAX_SENTENCES][MAX_CHARS];`

Comment: in function: `main()` the number of sentences is being input by the user, however; that is not being used when declaring `sentences[]`  SO 1)  the definition `MAX_SENTENCES can be ELIMINATED, then use the read-in value in a VLA (variable length array) definition of `sentences[]`  Similar considerations exist for the array: `questions[]`

Comment: in function: `readsentenceswithproduct()`, there is the huge allocation, on the stack of: `char temp[MAX_SENTENCES][MAX_CHARS];`

Comment: the places where the function: `my_strdup()` is called are failing to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: in function: `my_strdup()` when the call to `malloc()` fails, then should call `perror( "malloc failed" );` before returning to the caller

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(len > 0 && str[len-1] == c)` The function: `strlen()` returns the OFFSET/index to NUL Termination char. However, that may not be a '\n'.  Suggest using the single statement: str[ strcspn( str. "\n" ) ] = '\0'; Or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friend, I've managed to solve my problem! I'm posting the solution here in case someone runs into a similar problem in the future.

**Most of the errors shown in Valgrind were caused by a stack overflow**. My program was simply using too much memory. To solve that, I've changed the size of the `products` array to a reasonable one (I was using much more than what I actually needed!). Look below:

```
#define MAX_SENTENCES 32 //It was 100 before!
```

Note that even though the number of errors detected by Valgrind has decreased considerably with this, there are still some memory leaks in my program!

This, unfortunately, wasn't enough for run.codes to accept my program. Some operational systems use `\r` as the new line character (usually `\n`). I was using the function `fgets()` to read strings from the stdin. It also reads new line characters, in which I'm not interested, so I checked for them so they could be discarded. However, **I was only checking for `\n`**:

```
void readSentences(int count, char sentences[][MAX_CHARS]) {
        //...
        fgets(sentences[i], MAX_CHARS, stdin);
        if(sentences[i][0] == '\n') {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        //...
}
```

When **I really should also be checking for `\r`**:

```
if(sentences[i][0] == '\n' || sentences[i][0] == '\r') //{ ... }
```

This was the cause of the "Segmentation Fault" error on some environments. After solving that, my program worked fine on them!

Comment: A text input should only have `\n`s, including `stdin`.

Comment: strongly suggest moving those huge array declarations to file space (by prepending `static` to each array allocation.